# Remove symbol "/" at start and end of string

Tags: regex, scala

There is a string:

```
/text/text/text/
```

I'm a new in scala and don't know how to remove only start and end symbols "/". I know it's a regular expression, but how build it?

Comment: Please, at least try something before asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regex is not necessary:

```
"/text/text/text/" stripPrefix "/" stripSuffix "/"
```

or if you know they're always there:

```
"/text/text/text/".tail.init
```